# Cassandra add keyspace when cassandra is running as a service

Tags: c#, cassandra

My cassandra database is running as a service.
Now I want to add a new keyspace

When I would do it through the CMD/cqlsh it woul look like this:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE core_meter WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 3 };
```

How can I achieve this when Cassandra is running as a service?

I have a C# program communicating it, can I create a keyspace with C# code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a new keyspace in code by not calling the keyspace in the session like this:

```
  public void CreateKeyspace()
    {
        cluster = Cluster.Builder().AddContactPoint("192.168.30.104").Build();
        session = cluster.Connect();//
        session.Execute("CREATE KEYSPACE acc_meter WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 3 };");

    }
```